# Ruby: Failed to install gems via Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, heroku, rubygems

I'm having issues getting my ruby application to deploy on Heroku. When I push it through this is the error logs I'm getting. Even my ruby -v command won't work. Can't even bundle update or bundle install either. My GemFile reads ('rails', '3.2.11'), (gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3') (gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1') and (gem 'annotate', '2.5.0') (gem 'better_errors') (gem 'binding_of_caller'). I apologize for the messy formatting but any help works!

```
remote:        
remote:        current directory:
remote:        /tmp/build_b6e9988ad2a1c287bcb95782c7a546cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generator
remote:        /tmp/build_b6e9988ad2a1c287bcb95782c7a546cd/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/bin/ruby -I
remote:        /tmp/build_b6e9988ad2a1c287bcb95782c7a546cd/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r
remote:        ./siteconf20200430-264-zpgrl6.rb extconf.rb
remote:        creating Makefile
remote:        
remote:        current directory:
remote:        /tmp/build_b6e9988ad2a1c287bcb95782c7a546cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generator
remote:        make "DESTDIR=" clean
remote:        
remote:        current directory:
remote:        /tmp/build_b6e9988ad2a1c287bcb95782c7a546cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generator
remote:        make "DESTDIR="
remote:        compiling generator.c
remote:        In file included from generator.c:1:0:
remote:        ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h: In function ‘fbuffer_to_s’:
remote:        ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:175:47: error: macro "rb_str_new" requires 2 arguments, but
remote:        only 1 given
remote:             VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
remote:                                                       ^
remote:        ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:175:20: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer
remote:        without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
remote:             VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
remote:                            ^~~~~~~~~~
remote:        generator.c: In function ‘generate_json’:
remote:        generator.c:840:25: error: ‘rb_cFixnum’ undeclared (first use in this function);
remote:        did you mean ‘mFixnum’?
remote:             } else if (klass == rb_cFixnum) {
remote:                                 ^~~~~~~~~~
remote:                                 mFixnum
remote:        generator.c:840:25: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for
remote:        each function it appears in
remote:        generator.c:842:25: error: ‘rb_cBignum’ undeclared (first use in this function);
remote:        did you mean ‘rb_cFixnum’?
remote:             } else if (klass == rb_cBignum) {
remote:                                 ^~~~~~~~~~
remote:                                 rb_cFixnum
remote:        generator.c: At top level:
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’
remote:        cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-cast-function-type’
remote:        Makefile:244: recipe for target 'generator.o' failed
remote:        make: *** [generator.o] Error 1
remote:        
remote:        make failed, exit code 2
remote:        
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in
remote:        /tmp/build_b6e9988ad2a1c287bcb95782c7a546cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/json-1.8.0
remote:        for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to
remote:        /tmp/build_b6e9988ad2a1c287bcb95782c7a546cd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/json-1.8.0/gem_make.out
remote:        
remote:        An error occurred while installing json (1.8.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
remote:        succeeds before bundling.
remote:        
remote:        In Gemfile:
remote:          coffee-rails was resolved to 3.2.2, which depends on
remote:            railties was resolved to 3.2.11, which depends on
remote:              rdoc was resolved to 3.12.2, which depends on
remote:                json
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
```

Any help is appreciated, it seems JSON is giving me the most trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `bundle update json` or if it doesn't help, try to check if your bundler version is compatible with your version of rails

Comment: I've tried the bundle update json but it spits back an error saying "Could not find gem 'bundler (~> 1.0)', which is required by gem 'rails (=3.2.11)', in any of the sources."

Answer (score 0):

Rails 3.2 (and its dependencies such as your version of the `json` gem) is not compatible with Ruby 2.6. To fix this issue, you should preferably upgrade to a newer version of Rails (such as Rails 6.0). If you have a new rails app, you should start directly with a new Rails version. If you have an existing app, you probably need to perform code upgrades (which might be intensive) for your app to be compatible with the newer rails version.

If you have to use such an old (and long-time unsupported) version of Rails, you need to use an older version of Ruby. With Rails 3.2.11, the newest supported Ruby version is Ruby 1.9.2 which (besides being incredibly outdated) is only supported on Heroku's `Cedar-14` stack (which in turn will be removed on November 2, 2020 when you will definitely have to upgrade your app)

Thus, if you strictly have to stick to Rails 3.2, you should at least upgrade to 3.2.22.5 where you can use Ruby 2.2 (both of which are still out of support already). On Heroku, you then need to use the `Heroku-16` stack, which supports Ruby down to version 2.2.10.

Still, you should definitely try to upgrade your stack to use software versions updated less than 7 years ago...

Comment: Hello, thanks for the feedback! And yes the project is 6 years old and I was trying to update it as a project for this class but I can't figure out how to get heroku to deploy it even though the old version is still up and running. Since my project is 6 years old what course of action would you say I should go through. And I have time to perform code upgrades if that's what it takes to deploy it on heroku, I'm just trying to fix this formatting issue.

Comment: How would I downgrade to 1.9.2?

Comment: You need to use the Cedar-14 stack on Heroku and [select the right ruby version](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions). Check the Heroku documentation for details. Still, you should preferably upgrade your app. The Rails update (at least from 3.2.11 to r.2.22.5 which brings support for newer versions) is likely rather minor compared to having to support an incredibly old Ruby and OS stack.